# How to configure sql query shortcuts in SQL Workbench/J?

Tags: sql-workbench-j

I want to get rid of writing a full sql syntax, 
like I'm using for years in PL/SQL Developer editor or SQL SERVER Management Studio.

Examples:

```
count1 = select count(1) from
counthaving = select count(1) from having count(1)>?
s* = select * from
w = where
to_date = to_date('','dd/mm/yyyy')
sc* = select count(*) from
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for "text clips"? https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/macros.html

Comment: If I understood correctly, macros has other purpose, I'm looking for some text autoreplace inside editor sql page, for example, when I'll write "s*" this will be replaced with "select * from"

Comment: Yes, that's an [expandable macro](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/macros.html#expandable-macro)

Comment: Thanks for your help! @SQLWorkbenchJ

Answer (score 0):

This is what macros are intended for.

You can define a macro as ["expandable"](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/macros.html#expandable-macro) by selecting the "Expand while typing" check box in the macro definition.

If you type the "name" of such a macro in the editor and use the tab expansion key, the text will be replaced with the text of the macro.

It's recommended to un-check the option "Include in menu" for those macros.

Comment: One more small expansion, the macro name cannot include special characters such as "*" or "&", if so, the name won't be replaced. Thanks again